# double underline in Jaspersoft Studio Textfield

Tags: jasper-reports, text-styling

I am currently working on a jaspersoft report and i want to underline the grand total value of my invoice with a **double** underline.
I already tried it with the following HTML Style (Textfield Markup is set to HTML) :

```
"<h1 style=\"text-decoration: underline double;\"><u>"+$V{gesamtSumme}+"</u></h1>"
```

but this only shows the simple underline. I hope someone does have an answer to this.

Comment: From what I know JR supports only a small subset of HTML tags. You can't just write any HTML in there. `style` might be one of those unsupported ones. Actually I don't think you can get a real double underline in JR. The closest thing I can think of would be to use double line for field borders. Sadly it will have the fixed width of the field.

Comment: I would really like to avoid the fixed width of the second line. This seems to be a workaround, but not a real solution. Thank you anyway.